# Nexus Repository Manager 3.x connection failed

Tags: jenkins, nexus, nexus3

Using **Nexus Repository Manager 3.x Server** for connecting Nexus 3.  But the Test connection is failing with the below error.

---

Nexus Repository Manager 3.x connection failed

com.sonatype.nexus.api.repository.v3.impl.rest.NxrmResponseException: status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized
at com.sonatype.nexus.api.repository.v3.impl.rest.NxrmResponseHandler.handleResponse(NxrmResponseHandler.java:51)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:223)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:165)
at com.sonatype.nexus.api.repository.v3.impl.NexusRepositoryHttpClient.execute(NexusRepositoryHttpClient.java:83)
Caused: com.sonatype.nexus.api.exception.RepositoryManagerException: Get server version was unsuccessful (401 response from server)
at com.sonatype.nexus.api.repository.v3.impl.NexusRepositoryHttpClient.unsuccessfulEx(NexusRepositoryHttpClient.java:105)
at com.sonatype.nexus.api.repository.v3.impl.NexusRepositoryHttpClient.execute(NexusRepositoryHttpClient.java:86)
at com.sonatype.nexus.api.repository.v3.impl.DefaultNexusRepositoryV3Client.getVersion(DefaultNexusRepositoryV3Client.java:122)
at com.sonatype.nexus.api.repository.v3.RepositoryManagerV3Client$getVersion$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.sonatype.nexus.ci.config.Nxrm3Configuration$DescriptorImpl.doVerifyCredentials(Nxrm3Configuration.groovy:92)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:408)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:212)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:145)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:536)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:281)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:694)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:240)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1633)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:129)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:76)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
at hudson.plugins.audit_trail.AuditTrailFilter.doFilter(AuditTrailFilter.java:92)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:153)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:51)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:36)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:561)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1612)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1582)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates it's a Authentication failure. Can you check the credentials you are using to initiate the connection?

```
401, reason phrase: Unauthorized
```